# PostgreSQL populate_record and hstore

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, hstore

I am running Postgres 9.2.4 with hstore extension (on Windows)

Given a Table:

```
CREATE Table tmpM  (
id bigserial NOT NULL, 
EventId bigint NOT NULL, 
LoginId bigint NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT tmpM_key PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

I am trying to run this statement:

```
SELECT * from populate_record(null::tmpM, '"EventId"=>"123", "LoginId"=>"456"')
```

I am getting a result of 1 row, but all values are null. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Col names are quoted and hence not match the names in the table. Love Postgres, but case handling is ...ermmm...not so nice :-)

Comment: Error handling *is* nice in Postgres (much stricter than in most other DBMS actually) - just not with a "schemaless" (and non-validating) data type such as hstore.

Comment: Totally agree - what I was "whinging" about is how Postgre handles case sensitivity. In some dbms you can specify if schema is case sensitive or not. In Postgres there is no such setting...instead you have double quotes that maintain the case. Anyway our exp with Postgres has been very positive overall.

Comment: Postgres complies (with the requirements of SQL standard when it comes to quoted identifiers. The only part where it deviates is that the it folds everything to lower case whereas the standard requires to fold unquoted names to uppercase. Those "other" DBMS simply ignore (read: violate) the standard. (And please don't use "Postgre" - it's "Postgres")

Comment: Fair enough. BTW Postgre was a typo ;-)